# How to pass an ID in the onclick method without writing inline js coding

Tags: javascript, onclick

I have 200 rows of data with unique IDs.

```
foreach($IDs as $ID){
   <button onclick="deleteFunction($ID)">Delete</button>
}
```

Now, here in the button, I don't want to use inline JS, Is there any possible solution, that can avoid inline JS?

please, don't worry about the syntax. I just want to know the algorithm or any possible solution!

Answer (score 0):

When creating buttons you can give each button the id of `$ID` that way when the `deleteFunction()` is called it can access the id of the clicked element.

```js
for(const id of ['A', 'B', 'C']) {
    document.write('<button id="' + id + '" onclick="deleteFunction(this)">Delete</button>');
}

function deleteFunction(element) {
    console.log(element.id);
}
```